# Coloring geom_point() dots on a US Heat Map based on ZipCodes

Tags: r, ggplot2

Would very much appreciate some assistance in helping me color the geom_points using 5 different colors. Each point in the map represents a ZipCode. The data is laid out as follows

```
ID    zip     city      state    latitude     longitude    num    colorBuckets
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    00210    xxx       NH       43            -71.013     10         1
2    45013    yyy       OH       43            -88.304     200        5
.
.
```

I would like the `colorBucket 5` to appear as a dark red, `colorBucket 4` to appear as a lighted red and finally `colorBucket 1` to appear as a **very light grey**. Can someone help me with the code?

Here's what I have so far:

```
g <- ggplot(data=mapdata,
            aes(x=longitude, y=latitude)) + 
            geom_point(aes(fill=colorBuckets), size = 0.04) +
            scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-125,-66), breaks = NULL) +
            scale_y_continuous(limits = c(25,50), breaks = NULL) +
            labs(x=NULL, y=NULL)
```

I cant post an image yet [because i dont have 10 reputations yet - not sure that the even means].

But the current plot is coming up with all BLACK dots and the legend is showing various shades of blue with a scale going from 1 to 5.

I have tried unsuccessfully adding the following piece of code to the end of this snipper:

```
scale_fill_manual(values=c("<20"="red", "21 - 60" = "blue", "61 - 80" = "green", "81-100" = "yellow"))
scale_fill_brewer(palette="<palette name>")
scale_colour_nrewer(palette="<palette name>")
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: If you link to the image (say on imgur), Siddarth, someone will come along and edit it into your question. But probably the problem is that`colorBuckets` is numeric, and you want it to be a `factor`. Then `scale_color_manual` will work :)

Answer (score 1):

Had another comment, so I figured I should just post an answer. A few things going on here:

- check your column classes. If `ggplot` shows you a continuous color scale (as you describe), it's because your data is continuous. If you want 5 distinct colors, turn `colorBuckets` into a factor
- with `geom_point`, you should set `color`, not `fill`. (There's the edge-case if you use shapes 21:25 [then you can set both color and fill](http://www.endmemo.com/program/R/pchsymbols.php)

With the above changes, you can then use `scale_color_manual` if you know each of the colors you want, but from your description I think you'd do well with

```
+ scale_color_brewer(palette = "Reds")
```

Answer (score 0):

So this is what i ended up doing thanks to Gregor's feedback.

```
g <- ggplot(data=mapdata,
        aes(x=longitude, y=latitude)) + 
        geom_point(aes(color=factor(colorBuckets)), size = 0.04) +
        scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-125,-66), breaks = NULL) +
        scale_y_continuous(limits = c(25,50), breaks = NULL) +
        labs(x=NULL, y=NULL) +
        theme_bw() +
        scale_color_manual(values=c("bisque", "darkseagreen2", "maroon", "red")) +
        geom_polygon(data=states, aes(long, lat, group=group), fill=NA, colour="#000000") + 
        labs(x="", y="", title="Some Title")
```